# picklist update target primefaces 5

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using picklist of primefaces and I have the following problem, When I create an object , it works but when I try update this object, the target list comes empty.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <p:outputLabel id="lblDescricao" value="Descrição"/>
            <p:inputText id="txtDescricao" value="#{cadastroProdutoController.produto.descricao}" 
                         required="true" requiredMessage="Campo obrigatório" maxlength="30"/>
            <p:message id="msgDescricao" for="txtDescricao"/>
        </div>

        <div class="large-4 columns end">
            <p:pickList id="listTipoProduto" value="#{cadastroProdutoController.tipoProdutos}" var="tipoProduto"
                        itemLabel="#{tipoProduto.descricao}" itemValue="#{tipoProduto}">
                <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Não Associados</f:facet>
                <f:facet name="targetCaption">Associados</f:facet>

                <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{cadastroProdutoController.listaTodosTipoProdutoInner}" />
            </p:pickList>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 large-centered columns alinhamento_centro">
            <p:commandButton id="btnSalvar" value="SALVAR" validateClient="true" action="#{cadastroProdutoController.salvar}" update="@form"/>
            <p:spacer width="20px"/>
            <p:commandButton id="btnVoltar" value="VOLTAR" action="/paginas/cadastro/produtoPesquisa.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" immediate="true" ajax="false"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something wrong with your Converter or the Controller. Any code available to help?

And just my 2cents: If you want to have more people to help you, don't name your objects/id's in your foreign language. It's tricky to read.